# Constructing a infinite decimal out of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

I had a thought of constructing a infinite decimal out of prime numbers,like the following:
$$0.235711131719...$$
Is there a prove that show it's rational or irrational?

Comment: I asked this question (I do not remember when) and the answer was that it is irrational.

Comment: Dirichtlet's theorem is enough ensuring that every finite digit string (not beginning with a $0$) appears in this number which clearly implies that it cannot be rational.

Comment: @Peter Just to complete your answer, given a string of numbers $a_1 a_2\cdots a_n$ we can use Dirichlet theorem to find a prime $a_1 a_2\cdots a_n 1 \bmod (10^{n+1})$.

Comment: It looks transcendental.